# Why is dig failing but tcpdump showing a response?

Tags: networking, dns, udp

I have a situation where my dig command is failing with a timeout error when querying DNS over UDP, but when I check the packets with tcpdump it shows a valid response.

I have a working server to compare against and it seems that an additional packet is being sent on the failing host.

My dig command and output from the good host (names and IP addresses have been changed to protect the innocent) is:

```
[root@client1 ~]# dig +short @192.168.0.5 myhost.fqdn.com A
192.168.0.10
```

and the tcpdump command and output is:

```
[root@client1 ~]# tcpdump -i eth0 -nn src 192.168.0.5 or dst 192.168.0.5
13:16:58.656802 IP 192.168.0.2.19554 > 192.168.0.5.53: 58262+ [1au] A? myhost.fqdn.com. (59)
13:16:58.658654 IP 192.168.0.5.53 > 192.168.0.2.19554: 58262* 1/0/1 A 192.168.0.10 (75)
```

On the bad host I get this:

```
[root@client2 ~]# dig +short @192.168.0.5 myhost.fqdn.com A
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

and the tcpdump shows this:

```
[root@client2 ~]# tcpdump -i eth0 -nn src 192.168.0.5 or dst 192.168.0.5
15:35:54.000079 IP 192.168.0.2.26944 > 192.168.0.5.53: 44036+ [1au] A? myhost.fqdn.com. (59)
15:35:54.001738 IP 192.168.0.5.53 > 192.168.0.2.26944: 44036* 1/0/1 A 192.168.0.10 (75)
15:35:54.001771 IP 192.168.0.2 > 192.168.0.5: ICMP 192.168.0.2 udp port 26944 unreachable, length 111
```

The clients are Oracle Linux, the DNS server is Windows AD 2016, there's a hardware firewall that shows both TCP and UDP traffic is allowed through on port 53 and the Windows firewall logs also show the packets are accepted.

I'm at a loss as to why this would be failing (especially when it looks from tcpdump as though the server is actually responding with the record.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do the _Linux_ firewall logs show? It's the clients that are not accepting the response, not the DNS server.

Comment: It is likely an iptables issue, but no details are known about your setup. Since tcpdump captures the packets before the iptables firewall processes the packets, a packet shows up with tcpdump even if it gets blocked by the firewall.

Comment: You’re both right, thank you so much. I’d checked the services using systemctl for iptables and it wasn’t running, so I assumed it wasn’t going to be a client issue. Little did I know that on this Oracle Engineered System they were using iptables under a different name. Adding rules for UDP to the proprietary firewall got everything working. Thanks for interpreting my tcpdump. Really appreciated.